# product url comes with extra wrods

Tags: magento-1.9, product, url

http://example.com/dev/index.php/organic-wheat-flour-500g.html#.WCK-4bnpVBw

## .WCK-4bnpVBw dont know why this happen

Afer Url 11 digit tracking code are available.

How to remove this from url?

Comment: checked and its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to keep script inside your template file where you have defined your addthis social share code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var addthis_config = addthis_config||{};
    addthis_config.data_track_addressbar = false;
    addthis_config.data_track_clickback = false;
</script>
```

Remove cache and check.

Comment: its on website. not on social sharing

Comment: yes but you have to add this code inside your file. You have used addthis plugin for display social button on details page.

Comment: Refer this link, http://www.addthis.com/academy/removing-hashtags-anchors-and-tracking-codes-from-your-urls/

Comment: if you have used extension for addthis, you can keep this code in footer.

Comment: in which file i need to put this script ...path please

Comment: you can add this in footer file or product detail page catalog/product/view.phtml file at end of file.